# Simple Magento 2 rest API?

Tags: api, rest-api

Is this possible?   I want to make an API call to get orders, add shipment to order, and update product details via an API.   Right now it appears that I would need to use the api to login via Oauth every time.  I would like to automate syncing this kind of data up without the need to login with a user account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use the Token based authentication instad of OAuth, which is not the right choice for your use case anyways.

### How it works:

1. Request a token, using username and password (either customer or admin / API user):

   [image: get auth token example]

   **Admin token:**

   ```
    POST /V1/integration/admin/token
   ```

   **Customer token:**

   ```
    POST /V1/integration/customer/token
   ```
2. Use the returned token in following requests, using the `Authorization` HTTP header:

   ```
    Authorization: Bearer <authentication token>
   ```

**Source and full documentation:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: Thats so simple, not sure why I didnt catch this.  Thanks.